# Is it necessary Indexing app on google play

Tags: android

I'm creating a TicTacToe application in which a user can play against a computer, another player, another player through wifi/internet. My application doesn't have any links or connections to other application  Is indexing my application on google search is necessary, if yes how can I do that if I don't have any website.

Comment: Do you have a landing page? Where do you host you privacy policy?

Comment: no, I don't have any landing page, privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to make indexing of apps on Google Search to have the app on Play Store. As far as I understand your question.

But as @Jax has written maybe you need to add your privacy policy if you hold some user data on the web, but I don't know a thing about the law.
My idea is that you can simply add some privacy policy as .md file in Github public repository.